# How to show an element and hide when click on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of div elements which i trigger with the code below.

```
$(".course_id").on("click", function(){
     var id = $(this).data("id");
     $("div#lessons_by_course_" + id).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

The divs have an id called lessons_by_course + id e.g

```
<div id="lessons_by_course1"></div>
```

the id number is parsed dynamically using ruby on rails .each loop.

what i want is when i click on a div i want it to show and when i click on another div,i want jquery to hide the last one that was shown and show the one i clicked next.

Note that .course_id is a class for many elements so,each time i click on a certain one, a different div pops up because the id is different each time.

Comment: it's hard to understand the question..can you edit grammar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cache the id of the last shown element in a global variable:

```
var id;
```

Then in your loop:

```
$(".course_id").on("click", function(){
    if(id) {
        $("div#lessons_by_course_" + id).addClass("hidden");
    }
    id = $(this).id;
    $(this).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Note that `id = $(this).data("id");` might be merely `id = this.id;`!

Comment: You don’t have to select the element using the id you just extracted from it. `id = this.id; $(this).removeClass("hidden");`